# Android Http Request POST JSON

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a function to make a request, but it is giving some error, I already put permission to the internet, but still

This is my code:

```java
public String request(String Url,JSONObject Data){
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Url);
        InputStream inputstream;
        String content = "";


            try {

                httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(Data.toString()));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
          while(true){
              if(entity != null){
                  inputstream =   entity.getContent();
                  content = inputstream.toString();
                  break;
              }
          }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return ex.toString();
        } 

        return content;
}
```

Input:

```java
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
data.put("teste","teste");
String response = request('urlExample',data);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Output:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadExecption
```

Comment: You want to post data to API, so you need to do it on background not main thread. You can use something as simple as AsyncTask.

Comment: Hell no, I mean forget the asynctask, also, consider using a library like retrofit, which handles the threading and the most of the error handling

Comment: @barotia I understand your concern, but I think something as simple as AsyncTask solves his problem in this case. Later if he was interested he can go through Retrofit, RxJava, Kotlin coroutines and etc.

Comment: Why would you stick to something that's old, instead of learning the proper way? You'll learn a lot of unnecessary stuff this way

Comment: @barotia there's nothing wrong with AsyncTasks when properly used and disposed. Old and still functioning, is not something a lot of fancy "libraries" can claim. If all you need to do is a single request, there's no need to add Retrofit, RXJava, and let alone Coroutines (which are quite complicated to understand to new people).

Comment: Yes, I understand what you say, probably I was a little bit harch? Anyway, if somebody has to write a request, probably he will write a second one, a third one etc, anyway a retrofit is not hard at all, I wrote my very first requests with retrofit, and it was not complicated at all. And yeah, still better than just fireing a thread and just letting it  to go.

Comment: The core of your question is "why can't I just run this?", and the answer is because on Android you cannot do a long running process (like a network call) on the main/UI thread. If you do, Android complains and crashes your app.
Options to get a different thread are: Runnable, AsyncTask, RxJava (in no particular order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use AsyncTask as I mentioned in the comment :

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private String mUrl;
        private JSONObject mData;

        public LongOperation(String url, JSONObject data) {
           mUrl = url;
           mData = data;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return request(mUrl, mData);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response,
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

You can start your AsyncTask as follow:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
data.put("teste","teste");
new LongOperation('urlExample', data).execute();
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't exactly use this code, so I researched AsyncTask and I was able to develop it, thanks anyway your code can help me make

Answer (score 0):

Network operation does not be launched on Main Thread. You can create another Thread for running it.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){ 
     @Override public void run(){ 
         // Run request here !!!!
      } 
    });
thread.start();
```

Comment: Also don't do this ^ this thread doesn't support cancellation, doesn't use a ThreadPool, can't bubble stuff, etc. Just don't do this on Android when you have better mechanisms. Even an Executor pool is better.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to use `**Volley**`, it's a side client library which helps you with the Http-Request.

Search for `StringRequest`.