# how to POST a url Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

> Get a url like "http://TEST/Data.php?Name=ABC&Number=12"
>
> Want to post this url ,but not open this link.

Then Name and Number columns will change into ABC & 12.

setOnClickListener:

```
btn_send.setOnClickListener{
            val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://TEST/Data.php?Name=ABC&Number=12"))
            startActivity(i)

        }
```

This will open the link in a browser. How can I just post this url but not open it?

with this code my app crushed after click button:

```
btn_send.setOnClickListener{
            URL(url).readText()
        }
```

9/18 update----------------------------------

tring OKHTTP but nothing happened

```
fun get() {
            val client = OkHttpClient()
            val url = URL("http://TEST/Data.php?Name=ABC&Number=12")

            val request = Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build()
            OkHttpClient().newCall(request)

root.btn_submit.setOnClickListener {
            get()
        }
```

if I change `OkHttpClient().newCall(request)` into `OkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute()` app will crush

I think is there a problem when i send request to HTTP which is unsafe cause the error

Comment: Use the OkHttp library - see [here](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)

Comment: Take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57930178/android-http-request-post-json/57930329#57930329

Comment: If you don't want to use a library- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50272269/97714

Comment: some errors occur , still trying

Comment: update OKHTTP for the lastest trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just cannot directly open a POST URL in browser.

You have to use Library like one of the following:

- Retrofit
- Volley
- OkHttp

Or you can open it in WebView like below

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);
byte[] post = EncodingUtils.getBytes("Name=ABC&Number=12", "BASE64");
webview.postUrl("http://TEST/Data.php", post);
```

convert the above code into Kotlin

Comment: Create a new Activity and then Create a Webview in xml, then connect that webview in `kt` file, if still error occurred then check your URL with the post fields in POSTMAN to check if the POST request is working in Server end

Comment: i've update OKHTTP situation please take a look thanks

Comment: Using OKHTTP and solve the unsafe HTTP REQUSET problem

Comment: Now , POST success